# build table with dynamic columns number and order with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, database

first i am sorry for my English :)
i'm about to develop a CRM system and i want to give the user the option to choose how his leads table view gonna look like - i want him to have the option to decide which columns to show and in what order.
i still haven't decided about technologies i'm going to use - thought about mongodb to hold the leads and angularjs to show it.
can someone please give me advice about what will be the best way of doing it and if that's the right choice (mongodb, angularjs).

p.s 
most of the system will be built in laravel framework, just the leads part is about to use this technologies.

thanks a lot everyone, peach and love :)

Answer (score 0):

For the angular part in the view u can basicly render the table via ng-repeat as soon as you have your data from the mongodb. after that u can use custom filter to give the user the possibility to arrange the view to his needs.

Check this example out

[Scotch Table example Angular](http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/AmFLE)

```
<div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">
```

```
<p>Sort Type: {{ sortType }}</p>
<p>Sort Reverse: {{ sortReverse }}</p>
<p>Search Query: {{ searchFish }}</p>



 </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but that's not what i meant, i want the user to be able to re-order the table columns to what ever order he would like to for example i get this json from mongodb `{name:'some name',phone:'0554547852',email:'me@example.com'}` i want the user to have option to order the columns like so `{phone:'...',email:'...'}`, the other part was talking about which columns to show (the api will be able to get a lot of different values because it should feet a lot of different type of customers).

Comment: ah i only know kendoui

Comment: actually it's look like something i can use, is there something similar but free? :)

Comment: mh either semantic ui or jquery ui i guess https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/jqueryui